# Gradle openapi generator sources are not seen in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, openapi-generator

I am having trouble getting my generated code to be recognised by gradle/intellij. It does not work out of the box with the org.openapi.generator plugin and I have to add extra "fluff".

```
plugins {
    ....
    id("org.openapi.generator") version("7.3.0")
}

openApiGenerate {
    generatorName.set("spring")
    inputSpec.set("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/openapi.yml")
    outputDir.set("$buildDir/generated/sources/openapi")
    apiPackage.set("com.example.api")
    globalProperties.set(mutableMapOf(
        "models" to ""
    ))
    configOptions.set(mutableMapOf(
        "reactive" to "true",
        "useOptional" to "true",
    ))
}

tasks.compileJava.get().dependsOn(tasks.openApiGenerate.get())

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs("${openApiGenerate.outputDir.get()}/src/main/java")
        }
    }
}
```

However, this extra configuration then interferes with checkstyle and spotless plugin. Because I am now saying, through sourceSets that my generated code is a main source dir. And these code style plugin now also check this code.

I noticed gradle has the notion of annotationProcessors, which makes it so that code generated by, for example, MapStruct, gets recognised.
How can I get that same behaviour from code generated by the openapi plugin?